# Adjusting the height of Unity 4.6 UI Text according to content

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine

I am new to the unity's latest UI. What I know about UI Text Element is, we can wrap the text with in the horizontal bounds, but if it comes to next line, either it overflows or it truncates. If it fits in the height, font size decreases. What I want is to adjust the height of the text area according to the content it contains, without affecting the font size inside.

I will be having many text elements as childs to a parent panel, the panel itself will be child to a scrollable container. So I have to calculate height of all the children to adjust the height of the parent panel.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 10):

Add a `Content Size Fitter` component to `Text` and set its `Vertical Fit` to `PreferredSize`.

I wrote a blog so people might find it helpful knowing how I used this component to create dynamic lists.
http://mobile.folio3.com/creating-dynamic-scrollable-lists-with-new-unity-canvas-ui/

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Best fit" option under text script in UI Text Element. 
And set Min size and Max size value according to your need.